# Detecting handwritten boxes using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, handwriting-recognition

I have the following image:

[image]

I want to extract the boxed diagrams as so:

[image]

[image]

Here's what I've attempted:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('diagram.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw the contours
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Show the final image
plt.imshow(image), plt.show()
```

However, I've realized it'll be difficult to extract the diagrams because the contours aren't closed:

[image]

I've tried using morphological closing to close the gaps in the box edges:

```
# Define a rectangular kernel for morphological closing
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))

# Perform morphological closing to close the gaps in the box edges
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

But this changes almost nothing. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may replace morphological closing with dilate then erode, but **filling the contours** between the dilate and erode.

For filling the gaps, the kernel size should be much larger than 5x5 (I used 51x51).

---

Assuming the handwritten boxes are colored, we may convert from BGR to HSV, and apply the threshold on the saturation channel of HSV:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # Convert from BGR to HSV color space 
gray = hsv[:, :, 1]  # Use saturation from HSV channel as "gray".
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Apply automatic thresholding (use THRESH_OTSU).
```

---

Apply dilate with large kernel, and use `drawContours` for filling the contours:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (51, 51))  # Use relatively large kernel for closing the gaps   
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel)  # Dilate with large kernel

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(dilated, contours, -1, 255, -1)
```

---

Apply erode after filling the contours
Erode after dilate is equivalent to closing, but here we are closing after filling.

```
closed = cv2.erode(dilated, kernel)
```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('diagram.png')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # Convert from BGR to HSV color space 

# Convert to grayscale
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = hsv[:, :, 1]  # Use saturation from HSV channel as "gray".

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Apply automatic thresholding (use THRESH_OTSU).

thresh = np.pad(thresh, ((100, 100), (100, 100)))  # Add zero padding (required due to large dilate kernels).

# Define a rectangular kernel for morphological operations.
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (51, 51))  # Use relatively large kernel for closing the gaps

dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel)  # Dilate with large kernel

# Fill the contours, before applying erode.
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(dilated, contours, -1, 255, -1)

closed = cv2.erode(dilated, kernel)  # Apply erode after filling the contours.

closed = closed[100:-100, 100:-100]  # Remove the padding.

# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw the contours
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Show images for testing
# plt.imshow(image), plt.show()
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilated', dilated)
cv2.imshow('closed', closed)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

`gray` (saturation channel):
[image]

`thresh`:
[image]

`dilated` (after filling):
[image]

`closed`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just need to dilate the image to make the rectangle closed, then define a threshold for the area of the contours:

```
import cv2

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('diagram.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,1)

# Need to dilate the image to make the contours closed
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh,None)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate,None)

# Find contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erode,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    # Check if it is an external contour and its area is more than 8000
    if hierarchy[0,i,3] == -1 and cv2.contourArea(cnt)>8000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imwrite('template {0}.jpg'.format(i), image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
cv2.imshow('img',image)
```

You will get :

[image]